# Can't access app settings in test

Tags: appharbor

In an app on AppHarbor, I'm trying to access the app settings in my web.config from a unit test, but the settings all come back null.

For example, I have this in my web.config:

```
<add key="Environment" value="Test" />
```

My test class has this initializer:

```
Trace.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"]);
```

After build, when the tests run, this trace outputs a blank line. Any other keys I have in app settings also return null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `Environment` app setting is actually set to `Test` by the test runner, so you don't need to set it yourself.

You mention that you're trying to access the app settings in your `Web.config` file, but you need to add a configuration file specifically for your test project. I'd also expect other test runners to have the same behavior, so this should be similar to your local environment.

If you have already added a configuration file for your test project, make sure that the `Build Action` attribute on the file reference is set to `Content`. This will ensure that the file is copied to the build output directory and the configuration settings can be read as expected.

Comment: the Environment app setting here was just an example I gave specifically since I know it is supposed to be set automatically. The problem is I get blanks for any app setting I try to read, including Environment.

the build action is set to Content on the web.config, and the test class is a part of the same project that is being built.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly your test class is in your web project (containing the `Web.config` that you want to read values from)? That won't work - is it working for you locally? What test runner are you using?

Comment: You could get around this by adding an `App.config` file to your web project. That's a bit of a hack though and I'd recommend that you move your tests to a separate test project.

Comment: Yes, it is working locally with running the tests inside visual studio.